# How do I proceed after running this command?

Tags: php, terminal, server

I am very new to the server side of development, and I am trying to implement the Koel music streaming service. [Koel install](http://koel.phanan.net/#install). I have done everything up to the .env modification. I have modified it following [this guide](https://forum.laragon.org/topic/18/how-to-setup-koel-personal-music-streaming-server-in-10-simple-steps/2), I replaced the admin name, email, and password to fit my credentials. I am lost on what to do next, do I need to launch a localhost server, and then run the command `php artisan koel:init`?

Comment: The init command will start a local dev server for you. If you push this to production somewhere you should use a proper web server instead of the built in server.

Comment: Duly noted when I run the php command I get this error http://puu.sh/nLU4Q/fd50893a42.png

Comment: Verify that you have the correct database credentials in .env.

Comment: Am I suppose to enter specific credentials? http://puu.sh/nLU8O/6bdb755da7.png

Comment: Yes you need to enter valid database credentials. For those credentials to work you must have set up a database server on your machine

Comment: Ok that was my initial concern

Comment: How do I get the database credentials?

Comment: As said you will need to set up a database server. Since this is a Laravel (PHP framework) application you could use Laravels virtual machine called "Homestead". It comes with everything you need preinstalled. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead

Comment: I set up a node.js server, but I am still lost on what to input in the .env file

Comment: A node js server lets you run server side javascript. As said you need a database server